# PostgreSQL CROSSTAB incorrect output

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, pivot-table, postgres-crosstab

Running into issues using CROSSTAB in PostgreSQL to transform data from long to wide. Here are the tables that I get before and after running CROSSTAB.

[Table returned from source query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlqZd.png)

| agency | complaint_type | num_complaints |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DOHMH | Rodent | 31623 |
| DOHMH | Food Establishment | 10523 |
| DSNY | Smoking | 2473 |
| DSNY | Air Quality | 10432 |
| ... | ... | ... |

[Table returned after pivoting on column 'agency'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwEp8.png)

| complaint_type | DOHMH | DSNY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DOHMH | 31623 | 10523 |
| DSNY | 2473 | 10432 |

The output is incorrect as it does not retain the values in the 'complaint_type' column, but rather replaces the values with the new column headers "DOMHM" and "DSNY".

The code I used:

```
    CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS tablefunc;
    
    SELECT * FROM CROSSTAB($$
        SELECT agency, complaint_type, COUNT(*) AS num_complaints
        FROM (
            SELECT agency, complaint_type
            FROM general
            WHERE agency = 'DOHMH' OR agency = 'DSNY') AS subquery
        GROUP BY agency, complaint_type
        ORDER BY agency, num_complaints DESC;
                           $$) AS ct (
        complaint_type text,
        "DOHMH" bigint,
        "DDSNY" bigint);
```

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Could you share the data in plain text? Images don't work in the SQL editors I know of

Comment: Hi Frank! Yes, I added the data as tables. Thank you @FrankHeikens